# async Main in C# and blocking async Http calls

Tags: c#, concurrency, .net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

i feel pretty confused by the output i'm getting out of what i believe is purely async program.
As you can observe there are no obvious anti patterns (i hope) and blocking calls.

`slowURL` throttles server response for 10 seconds. I did confirm by running calls to the local server with 10 second timeout that `FetchSlowAsync` method call effectively blocks the main thread for 10 seconds when running the code in console.

I expected that TaskScheduler would schedule the calls not in a sequential manner but by always randomly determining the method call order. Alas the output is always deterministic.

```
FetchSlowAsync start
FetchSlowAsync got data!
FetchAsync start
FetchAsync got data!
FetchBingAsync start
FetchBingAsync got data!
All done!
```

My question is: what prompts `FetchSlowAsync` to block rather than TaskScheduler to perform a context switch to another async method and get back to it when it's done?

And the next question that follows the former: why all the methods in `async Main` are executed in the same order as they are being called given the async execution model is concurrent?

```cs
using static System.Console;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Start
{
    const string serviceURL = "https://google.com";
    const string slowDown = "http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/10000/url/";
    const string slowURL = slowDown + serviceURL;
    const string OkURL = serviceURL;

    static async Task FetchSlowAsync()
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchSlowAsync start");
        await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(slowURL); //BLOCKS MAIN THREAD FOR 10 seconds        
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchSlowAsync got data!");
    }

    static async Task FetchAsync()
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchAsync start");
        await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(OkURL);
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchAsync got data!");        
    }

    static async Task FetchBingAsync()
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchBingAsync start");
        await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://bing.com");
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("FetchBingAsync got data!");
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        await FetchSlowAsync();
        await FetchBingAsync();
        await FetchAsync();

        await System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("All done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind if I refactored your code to not include local methods? There's no need for them here, and they're just added complexity.

Comment: Next, it sounds like you're expecting these to happen in parallel. Why? You're always awaiting whatever asynchronous task you've just started. You're awaiting the task returned by `FetchSlowAsync()` before you call `FetchBingAsync()`, for example.

Comment: (I can write that up in more detail as an answer, if you like. But it really depends on whether/why you expected things to happen in parallel.)

Comment: @JonSkeet sure Jon, i don't mind. That snippet was added for demo purposes only since my expectations of execution heavily differ from the output.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you already answered this well enough

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto pardon, but my intention wasn't to ask how to parallelise the code but rather to figure why the scheduler doesn't context switch on slow running IO.

Comment: Why would it? How would it know it's "slow running"? How do you decide when it's slow and when it isn't?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i leave that decision to the runtime itself
Take a look at a similar implementation in Go https://pastebin.com/Uzs4Hd4m

Comment: That looks *far* more similar to what Jon Skeet answered than to your code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto well, the default `async/await` doc makes the impression that all thing are taken care of by the CLR itself while in Go i should state things explicitly.
I didn't realise topmost `await` call will basically block until async task returns.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should read the documentation on async, await and TPL in general. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) "The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to insert a suspension point in the execution of the method until the awaited task completes"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, you're waiting for the task returned from `FetchSlowAsync()` to complete before moving on to call `FetchBingAsync` etc. You're doing that by awaiting the tasks, here:

```
await FetchSlowAsync();
await FetchBingAsync();
await FetchAsync();
```

If you don't want to wait for the slow fetch to complete before you start the Bing fetch, etc, you can remember the tasks returned by them, and await them later:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    // Start all three tasks
    Task t1 = FetchSlowAsync();
    Task t2 = FetchBingAsync();
    Task t3 = FetchAsync();

    // Then wait for them all to finish
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("All done!");
}
```

*Now* you get the kind of output I think you're expecting. For example, here's one run on my machine:

```
FetchSlowAsync start
FetchBingAsync start
FetchAsync start
FetchAsync got data!
FetchBingAsync got data!
FetchSlowAsync got data!
All done!
```

Comment: i guess i was expecting a bit more from C#'s async than it can actually give. I thought that if  `await`  exceeds IL instruction or time threshold it switches to the main thread and it will pick up the next async method to execute (in case of my code).

Comment: @alexeyhaidamaka: I would say that's not "expecting more" but "expecting very different" - and I think it would be much worse, by being *far* less predictable. If an `await` operator could just get bored and proceed with the next statement, what would you expect it to do if you were using the result of the `await` operator? It's really important to understand what async/await actually do, because then you can decide on the behavior you want.